# Transaction with One SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I'm learning how to program by creating a blog, and one of the requirements that I have is to increment the "count" column of a post category whenever a new blog post is created.

As for now, I have to use the following statements to accomplish this task:

```
INSERT INTO posts (..., ..., category_id) VALUES (..., ..., 5);
UPDATE categories SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 5
```

Is there any way for me to combine these two into a single SQL statement? If not, is there a way to "automate" the increment of the count field whenever I created a new post with that category?

Comment: @Oded I'm sorry - I'm using MySQL 5.5.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate this by using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

```
CREATE TRIGGER myPostsTrigger AFTER INSERT
ON posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE categories SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = NEW.category_id
END
```

Then, when you insert a row into posts (`INSERT INTO posts (..., ..., category_id) VALUES (..., ..., 5);`), it will automatically increment your count.

Answer (score 2):

you can't combine the statements, because they're doing two different operations on different tables. But wrapping them in a transaction effectively makes them an atomic pseudo-single statement:

```
start transaction;
insert into posts blah blah blah;
update categories blah blah blah;
commit;
```

You could update thigns by using a trigger on the posts table. Any time a record is inserted or delete, you'd have the trigger run the update query.